# Feed /dev/random by Octeon RNG

Tags: kernel-modules, random

The device is Octeon by Cavium which contains a RNG hardware unit. OS shows that the current entropy pool size is 4096 bytes but `entropy_avail` is very low. The device crypto modules has `ansi_cprng.ko` present only, no other RNG related `.ko` is present. Additionally, as per `lsmod`, no RNG related modules are loaded, even though the kernel configuration settings related to RNG are as following;

```
CONFIG_CRYPTO_ANSI_CPRNG=m
CONFIG_CRYPTO_HW=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_RNG=m
CONFIG_CRYPTO_RNG2=y
```

How to feed `/dev/random` from Octeon RNG and increase `entropy_avail`?

Answer (score 1):

**Enable [CONFIG_HW_RANDOM_OCTEON](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/HW_RANDOM_OCTEON.html).**

This will build the [`octeon-rng`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/char/hw_random/octeon-rng.c) driver that automatically feeds the kernel entropy pool (by calling `devm_hwrng_register`).

Comment: In addition CONFIG_HW_RANDOM is also required which will generate rng-core.ko as octeon-rng.ko depends on rng-core.ko. Having said that after loading both modules still the entropy remains less then 200, previously it was 143.

Answer (score 0):

When both rng modules octeon-rng & rng-core are loaded the **/dev/hwrng** device is created, */sys/class/misc/hw_random/rng_current* &
*/sys/class/misc/hw_random/available* will show name octeon. However another application **rng-tools** is required.

The command;

> rngd -o /dev/random -r /dev/hwrng

will feed the kernel entropy from RNG and
raise entropy_avail to approx 3000 bytes.

Further rngtest can be conducted for FIPS140-2 randomness test by command;

> rngtest -c 1000 < /dev/random

Having said that still If some one can tell;

- Why rngd command with verbose option on octeon shows that RNG is *Intel hardware RNG*.
- Secondly in rngd command if only */dev/random* is mentioned is it also effective for */dev/urandom*.